# How to declare field type DATETIME and set the default value

Tags: datetime

I have a problem but with the following code. I am creating the following Schema:

```
  $schema['billfold'] = [
    'description' => 'Stores example person entries for demonstration purposes.',
    'fields' => [
      'pid' => [
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique person ID.',
      ],
      'data' => [
        'type' => 'datetime_default',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'The date when the update has been done.',
      ],
    ]
  ];
```

How Can I set the type "Datetime" and default value of ON UPDATE (for istance)???

Comment: I did it only from phpMyAdmin

Comment: Drupal's DB schema APIs don't support MySQL triggers (probably because they're not available in every DBMS). Continue adding them manually, or maybe as part of an update hook. For DBMS-specific types, you can use, for example, `mysql_type` instead of `type`. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7.x for more info

Comment: @Clive thank you for your suggestion!